# Is it ok to ask two open questions with similar content

Tags: discussion

I have stated a problem and later it occurred to me, I might made the X-Y mistake. Since I asked intentionally to solve Y but meant X I am now wondering, if it is ok to make a new question towards X or should I try to change the question to Y but therefore changing the content of Y? Furthermore is linking the two question an absolute no-go or emphasized since the answers might not be unrelated. It directly concerns these two: [X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224995/how-to-have-several-sessions-for-same-user) and [Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156546/reset-session-in-jsp-without-invalidating), but I am wondering what the best attempt is to do this.

Comment: Well, don't leave the Y question lying around.  Delete it if you still can.

Comment: Since question Y has already an answer, which is just not completely satisfactory I refrain from deleting it. I would prefer merging them, but then again the original intent of question Y would get changed. Also nobody wants to read 2 pages just to read the question. It is more that X is the design problem and Y was an so far fruitless attempt to solve it.

Comment: If the question that has problem Y has an answer that solves Y but not X, accept the answer and ask your new question about X. changing question Y to ask about X instead when it already has an answer for Y isn't a good idea. Otherwise just leave the old question alone.

Comment: You definitely can't change the Y now that there's an answer. The questions don't look like duplicates to me so I think having both is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. It's ok.** If the other question is stale or has an answer, why not? 
Since you understand your problem better you can write a more specific and clear question with relevant code samples etc.

The new question might also more likely to be useful for others in the future, when you can start with a blank slate with no potentially outdated comments and answers.

You are the best judge on whether this is worth a new question or not. If someone thinks it's a duplicate they can flag it.